# How can I use R to run a confirmatory factor analysis model with a large and sparse data matrix?

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I have a large and sparse data matrix (2000 persons, 16082 items) on which I want to run a confirmatory factor analysis. The items (item1, ..., item16082) have been uniquely assigned to one of five factors (F1, ..., F5), though these factors are correlated. As a result, I suspect that the items will load significantly on factors other than the one assigned.

How do I set this up in R?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the Lavaan package.

They have a great website with tutorials as well!  Let me know if I can be of any more help.

http://lavaan.ugent.be/

The syntax would work as follows:

```
    model <- '
     # latent variables
     F1=~ x1 + x2 + x3
     F2 =~ x4 + x5 + x6 + x7
     F3 =~ x8 + x9 + x10 + x11
     F4 =~ .......
     F5 =~.......
```

```
    fit <- sem(model, data=data)
    #Print model summary
    summary(m1,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Is there a way to assign a factor when there are a large number of indicators, such as

`F1 =~ x1 + x2 + .... + x100`

Comment: you can use common string manipulation methods in `R`, such as paste. But to my knowlege the lavaan syntax does not provide an array or looping feature.

Comment: To follow up as well, "I phoned a friend" (my previous SEM instructor) and he was not aware of a simple method that you are looking for either.  However, he did say that mplus has this function. you can download the trial version; however, I am not sure if it will have this function.  I am sorry I do not have the answer you werelooking for!